# python defaultdict lambda

Tags: python, defaultdict

I'm trying the defaultdict in python. the code is as follows:

```
dd = defaultdict(lambda :[0,0])
dd[5][4] = 2
print(dd)
```

But it throws an IndexError

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

and once i change the code to

```
dd[2][1] = 2
```

the result is :

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001F9F10EE730>, {2: [0, 2]})
```

I don't know why index out of range and how the range comes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `defaultdict` generates a default entry which has a length of 2.

When you do `dd[5][4] = 2`, since key `5` doesn't exist, `defaultdict` generates a `[0,0]` value as expected.

Then you're accessing the 5th index, which is out of range (like you'd do `[0,0][4] = 2`)

(of course it works with `dd[2][1] = 2` because `1` is within default list range)

If you don't know the size of your lists and you don't want to know, I suggest to use a default dictionary on a default dictionary of integers, like this:

```
dd = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
```

(of course that doesn't generate an array but a dict of dicts, but the `dd[5][4]` construct works right away)